# How to get the current version of a composer dependency inside a php script?

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

Is there a way to get the current version of slim? Like a php code expression or such that would display the real version the script is currently running?

Comment: I searched the web, there is currently no question about: "how to get the version of a composer dependency". So it would be nice, when the question could be rewrite that it can be better found. Could you do this, if not I would do this too, if you allow it.

Comment: yes, sure, you can do it I allow you. I prefer you do it so it matches exactly the situation you describe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the `composer.lock`-file to get the version of that dependency.

```
$composerLock = json_decode(file_get_contents('composer.lock'));
foreach($composerLock->packages as $package) {
    if ($package->name == 'slim/slim') {
        $version = $package->version;
        break;
    }
}
echo $version;
```

In slim there is also a `VERSION`-constant on the `App`(v3.x) or `Slim`(v2.x) class

```
// 2.x
$app = \Slim\Slim;
$version = \Slim\Slim::VERSION;

// 3.x
$app = \Slim\App;
$version = \Slim\App::VERSION;
```